# How do I convert float tensor into binary tensor using PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor and want to convert in into a Quantized Binary form.

`x= torch.Tensor([-9.0387e-01,  1.4811e-01,  2.8242e-01,  3.6679e-01,  3.2012e-01])`

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch only supports qint8 type.
You can convert the tensor to a quantized version with `torch.quantize_per_tensor`, you can check the wiki [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.quantize_per_tensor.html).